# Allow multiple active connections to MS SQL database using VS datasets

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

So I use a Visual Basic DataSet on an ASP.Net website, and when multiple users access the website I get something along the lines of:

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is Open.

Can I create multiple connections to the SQL database?

I know the datasets have normal code behind them so I'm wondering if I could modify something in those files to create a new connection for each user session.

I've tagged c# because if an answer pops up in c# I'll convert it...

Comment: Is your connection static / shared?

Comment: A shared connection I believe, I haven't changed anything (apart from adding tables) to the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multi-threaded, multi-user environment like ASP.NET, you have to stay away from shared connections. You're better off creating the connection as needed and then disposing of it. Behind the scenes .NET will use connection pools, and SQL Server won't have any problems handling lots of multiple connections. Pseudo-code:

```
    ' SQLCommand to fill DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection("someconnectionstring")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        cnn.Close()
    End Using

    ' TableAdapter to fill DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim ta As New SqlDataAdapter
    ta.Fill(ds)

The [Using statement][1] lets .NET handle the disposal of the connection for you.
```

Comment: Yes, but `Close()` is redundant within `using`.

Comment: @Crowcoder And `.Open()` is redundant when using `.Fill()` like that.

Comment: I've converted existing XSD code into a vb file, can I use the generated classes and functions in the way you have specified above?

Comment: You can, although moving the autogenerated code into your own VB file will make updating the code a bit of a hassle. It rather defeats the purpose of having a graphical code-generation tool like the dataset designer...

Comment: @Crowcoder -- true enough, if the connection is still open when you hit `end using` then it will close it for you. Still, no harm in closing it explicitly and remembering to always pair an `Open()` with a `Close()` is not a bad habit to get into! @Andrew is correct as well. I'll see if I can update the example...

Comment: @Hobbes There is no need to always pair an open with a close. Only do so when you need to do so. Don't leave useless code in.

Comment: @Hobbes I've been using the dataset designer to generate the code. Converted XSD into VB using xsd.exe. As you say it is a bit of a hassle even looking at it. I have around 23 tables (this is a student management system that will be in use in a college starting next year onwards!) Anyway, what would you advise me to do if I've used the dataset designer to make the code for 100+ queries? If I said I didn't think this would be a problem when I started would be a poor excuse ;)